# set preferred choice in entity type form

Tags: symfony

I have the following entity type form element in symfony2:

```
 ->add('member_type', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'AdminBundle:CustomerTier',
                    'property' => 'tier',
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'required' => true,
                        )
                )
```

This gives checkboxes. In the edit view i want to checked the already selected choices when adding.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The default data on edit should already be checked if you retrieve the entity from the database and apply it to the form. We need to see your controller to see where the problem is.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue.
On another part of the application the two Entities are actually related, but the case with the problem doesn't have an Entity Association.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean checking a checkbox in the view (twig)?

```
{{ form_widget(form.checkme, { 'attr': {'checked': 'checked'} }) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.. This is not the case .. I need only select some of them that are stored in the database. For example three check boxes green,blue and red. when adding user checked only blue and red, I want to check only blue and red in the edit view.